# Canvas background change

Tags: php, html, canvas, background, processing

I wanted to edit this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Qfwmm/ to change background to image.
What I did was:

```
 bg = loadImage("example.jpg");

void setup() {
size(500,500);
frameRate(25);
background(bg);
```

on the website console now it says :

> Uncaught Error using image in background(): PImage not loaded.

Image and canvas are same height/width. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you preloading? Try adding this:

```
/* @pjs preload="example.jpg"; */
```

[Documentation](http://processingjs.org/reference/preload/)